# Cannot open load file : no such file or directory , semantic-load

Tags: emacs, jdee

I am trying to install `jdee`on my `emacs`,and this is my configuration in `.emacs`:

```
(require 'cedet)
(add-to-list 'load-path (format "%s/jdee/lisp" "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
(autoload 'jde-mode "jde" "JDE mode" t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.java\\'" . jde-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
```

but when I edit java file , it reports an error:

```
File mode specification error:
(file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "semantic-load")
```

and then I download the `cedet-1.1`,find there is a `smantic-load.el` file in the cedet-1.1 directory

`emacs` version : `24.5`
`jdee` version  : `2.4.0.1`
`OS platform`  : `windows 7`

How to fix this?

Comment: What does `C-h v load-path` tell you? Is your `cedet-1.1` directory in that list? If not, add it to `load-path` and try again.

Comment: if I load path of `cedet-1.1`,then load file `cedet.el` , It will report some other errors.So I decide to choose` cedet-2.0` instead of `cedet-1.1`,but It seems that there is big difference between `version 1.1` and `version 2.0`.If I only use `cedet`,It will work well .Should I choose `cedet-1.1` instead of `cedet-2.0`

Comment: No idea what you should choose; sorry. I'm not sure I even understand what your comment says. My point was that if file `semantic-load.el[c]` is not in a directory that is in your `load-path` then it is normal that Emacs complains that it cannot load it. The directories in `load-path` are where Emacs looks for libraries to load.

Comment: Because my emacs version is `24.5`,the `cedet-2.0` is built in installation . I try to find the file `semantic-load.el` in `emacsInstallPath/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/cedet` directory , but there is nothing.So I downloaded `cedet-1.1` from Internet.To my suprise, there is the file `semantic-load.el` in `cedet-1.1` directory .T_T if I use `cedet-1.1` instead of built-in `cedet`, my emacs will report many other errors

Comment: If `semantic-load.el` is nowhere under the Cedet 2.0 installation then why do you think you need it? Why are you trying to load it if it is no longer included with Cedet? And what does this have to do with `jde-mode`? Is that germane to your problem and question? It sounds like you are using some library (perhaps `jde-mode.el`?) that requires you to use Cedet 1.1, not Cedet 2.0. Just a guess.

Comment: The error occurs everytime when edit java source file.In other word , If switch to `jde-mode`,some exceptions will be thrown. Maybe `cedet 2` is not compatible with `jdee`.anyway ,thx.